# Facebook Login Button handling

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook login button in my app but when user clicks on login I have to get his current location using gps
I am able to show the alert dialog for GPS not enabled if its not enabled it should not redirect to Facebook login page, but it still goes to facbook login page

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.act_reg_fb_login);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

handling the login button click listner

```
case R.id.act_reg_fb_login:
        if(isGettingHomeEntityData)

{
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("email");
    permissions.add("user_likes");
    permissions.add("user_location");
    permissions.add("user_actions.books");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            if (loginResult.getAccessToken() == null) {
                showSignUpLoginIssue(Constants.ErrorIssue.ERR_WHILE_LOGIN);
            } else {
                getEmailFromFaceBookAndLogin(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            UIUtility.showSnackBar(coolMain, getString(R.string.err_facebook_cancelled));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e("fb error", String.valueOf(error));
            UIUtility.showSnackBar(coolMain, error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
    break;
}

else

{
    initializeLocationVariables();
    break;
}
```

Comment: post the full code where is `isGettingHomeEntityData` defined?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 `isGettingHomeEntityData` is boolean value

Comment: if it returns wrong value then `onSuccess` method will be called

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 values are correctly passed as soon as I click login button it shows the `alert dialog` and then redirects to mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in onCreate() of your Activity

```
 private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            updateWithToken(newToken);
        }
    };
    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
```

Also in onStop()

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
}
```

in `updateWithToken()` method:

```
 private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: shouldn't `accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();` be in `onDestroy()`?